# WPF EF DB connection string : Error when using attached db in connection string

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, windows-installer

**THIS CONNECTION STRING WORKS**

On my Local system i was using the database connection string

```
<connectionStrings>    
<add name="GaugeSelectorEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Gage.csdl|res://*/Gage.ssdl|res://*/Gage.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=GEORGE1\SQL08R2;Initial Catalog=GaugeSelector;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />   
</connectionStrings>
```

This works perfectly fine.

**CHANGED TO ATTACH DB FILE INSTEAD AND IT THROWS ERROR**

Now i have to deploy the WPF application and so i want to attach the mdf file from the database. So as suggested from existing resources on web i change the string to

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="GaugeSelectorEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Gage.csdl|res://*/Gage.ssdl|res://*/Gage.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=GEORGE1\SQL08R2;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB\GaugeSelector.mdf;Initial Catalog=GaugeSelector;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

The only change being

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB\GaugeSelector.mdf;
```

I infact copied the mdf file of database from it's location to a folder DB in the executable path. By the way i was using LINQ to EF. But now i start getting the error.

```
{"The underlying provider failed on Open."}
```

Now i read somewehere it might happen if object context is not opened. So i put

```
GSData.Connection.Open();
```

But now it breaks here with the same error.
Is my approach itself wrong (Then what should be the approach) or do i just need some minor corrections on the connection string?

Comment: Is each user running their own database instance?

Comment: Each user has his own database instance